# JQueryValidation plugin error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined"

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm having some problems with the excellent JQueryValidation plugin.

I have read some similar questions and the common thread with them seems to be that a plugin method isn't included - however, the remote and type methods are in the core of the plugin and don't need to be included.

Another odd detail is that the registerEmail field usually validates when the input blurs.

When you type into the registerEmail field, it validates fine, but the error sometimes shows and sometimes it doesn't.

When you click the Submit button, the error always shows.

Here is my relevant code:

**HTML**

```
<form id="registrationForm" action="dostep2.asp" method="get">

     <input type="text" id="registerName" name="registerName" placeholder="Enter your Name." />
     <input type="text" id="registerEmail" name="registerEmail" placeholder="Enter your Email Address." />

     <button type="submit" name="submitButton1" value="submitButton1" class="btn btn-default btn-lg proceed">
          </span>Proceed to <strong>Payment</strong> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right">
     </button>

</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script src="js/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

        var validator = $("#registrationForm").validate({

            debug: true,

            rules: {

                registerName: {
                    required: true
                },

                registerEmail: {
                    required: true,
                    email:true,
                    remote: "http://beta.mysite.com/Testmail.asp",
                    type: "get"
                },

                registerPassword: {
                    required: true
                },

                registerPasswordConfirm: {
                    required: true,
                    equalTo: "#registerPassword"
                },

                registerSub: {
                    required: true,
                    type: "get",
                    remote: "http://beta.mysite.com/testsub.asp"
                }

            },

            messages : {

                registerName: "Please type in your name.",
                registerEmail: "Please type in your e-mail.",
                registerPassword: "Please type in your password.",
                registerPasswordConfirm: "Please confirm your password.",
                registerSub: "Please type the subdomain you want to use."

            }


        });

    </script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quote OP**:

> *" the `remote` and `type` methods are in the core of the plugin and don't need to be included."*

Not quite.  `remote` is a method but `type` is not...

```
registerEmail: {
    required: true,
    email:true,
    remote: "http://beta.mysite.com/Testmail.asp",
    type: "get" // <- this is not a method or rule
},
```

`type` is an option of `remote` and therefore goes *inside* of it...

```
registerEmail: {
    required: true,
    email: true,
    remote: {
        url: "http://beta.mysite.com/Testmail.asp",
        type: "get"  // <- this is an option of 'remote'
    }
},
```

**See:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/**

However, since `type: "get"` is already the *default*, you should be able to leave it out entirely...

```
registerEmail: {
    required: true,
    email: true,
    remote: "http://beta.mysite.com/Testmail.asp"
},
```